# Unbinding scrolling after reviews have loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to load reviews when the user scrolls to an element. However, it takes a second for the reviews to load so if I unbind immediately after it breaks the review loading.

So my code should be I check my position everytime I scroll. If I I have reached the element "#media_reviews" then I load in my reviews through calling the library and then a callback function the uses the library like loadreviews. It takes a second for those to load then I want to unbind scrolling.

```
(jQuery)(window).scroll(function () {
    if((jQuery)(window).scrollTop() + (jQuery)(window).height()>=
(jQuery)('#media_reviews').offset().top){
    loadBazaarvoiceApi(configbv);
    loadBazaarvoiceApi(show_question);
    loadBazaarvoiceApi(showcontent);
    loadBazaarvoiceApi(loadreviews);

    (jQuery)(window).unbind('scroll');

    }
})
window.loadBazaarvoiceApi = function(callback) {
<?php $bvApiUrl = Mage::helper('bazaarvoice')->getBvApiHostUrl(true); ?>
    var bvapiUrl = "<?php echo $bvApiUrl ."/bvapi.js";?>"
            if (window.$BV) {
                callback();
            } else {
                (jQuery).ajax({
                    url: bvapiUrl,
                    cache: true,
                    dataType: "script",
                    success: function() {
                        (jQuery)($BV.docReady);
                        callback();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

Comment: Was there a sale on parentheses somewhere ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There is just a requirement of the cms I am using. It is using a prototype so I have to use (jQuery) as opposed to $.

Comment: No, you don't have to use the parentheses, nor do you have to use `jQuery`, but that's not really important, it sounds like you want to wait for the `loadBazaarvoiceApi` function calls to complete before you unbind the event, and for anyone to be able to answer that, you have to add the `loadBazaarvoiceApi` code as well.

Comment: I added the function call